# Passing webform submissions into new link - including email field breaks the link

Tags: webform-civicrm, email, tokens

I have a contact update webform using civi/drupal that is a precurser to an event sign up (which exists on a separate platform). The event sign up page uses the following fields to prefill the form:

first name |
last name |
email |
job title |
organisation |

so on the drupal contact form email confirmation, I added a link to the event sign up form using the following after the url:

?firstname=[webform_submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name]&surname=[webform_submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_last_name]&email=[webform_submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_email_email]&company=[webform_submission:values:civicrm_2_contact_1_contact_organization_name]&job_role=[webform_submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_job_title]

expecting the result to be e.g.

test.com?firstname=John&surname=Doe&email=John@doe.org&company=John Doe Inc&job_role=Director

displaying as a text link ie [click here](https://test.com?firstname=John&surname=Doe&email=John@doe.org&company=John%20Doe%20Inc&job_role=Director)

The problem is the email field. adding this completely breaks the link, it returns this:

```
 john@doe.org&company=John Doe Inc&job_role=Director">click here.
```

the email is then the only thing hyperlnked but only contains part of the url.

Is there any way to make sure the sumbitted values all stay within the text link so the user can click on the link and go to the pre-filled event form as intended?

Note: they originally get an invitation via civimail which uses ?firstname={contact.first_name}.. etc but I've added this update form in case some details are out of date. They can't then go back to the original invite email because the values are all passed though from the previous data, I need a way to get them to go to the event form using the updated details.

Comment: Update on this: we got around it in the end by making the email element a textfield instead. doesn't seem ideal so curious if there is another way.